# get error when using to_char function to extract date from a timestamp in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a quick test to use `to_char` to extract just the year-month-day from a timestamp as below:

```
select to_char('1999-01-08 04:05:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

but get error:

```
ERROR:  function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: select to_char('1999-01-08 04:05:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42725
Character: 8
```

please help. thanks

Comment: If the column is a timestamp you can simply CAST it to a DATE. But if it's a string  apply TO_DATE (not TO_CHAR).

Comment: '1999-01-08 04:05:06' - it is not timestamp, its text. You can start with select to_char('1999-01-08 04:05:06'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that the first argument I put in `to_char` is a text, not a timestamp, that caused this error. I should cast it to a timestamp and then get what I expected. as User9123 pointed out, should be like this

```
select to_char('1999-01-08 04:05:06'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert to a date; you already have a string:

```
select to_date(substring('1999-01-08 04:05:06', 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Or:

```
substring('1999-01-08 04:05:06', 1, 10)::date
```